# EF adds new many to many records to table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, relational-database

Context Class
Here is my context class. It sort of works in that in the BlogsPostTags table it adds IDs of the post and IDs of the tags ... however it adds NEW tag IDs, not exsisting tags that are already stored in the database.

```
public class WebsiteDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<BlogPost>().HasRequired(bp => bp.Author).WithMany(a => a.BlogPosts);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<BlogPost>().HasMany(bp => bp.Tags).WithMany(t => t.Posts).Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapLeftKey("BlogPostID");
            m.MapRightKey("TagID");
            m.ToTable("BlogPostTags");
        });
    }
}
```

What I want to happen:

```
Tag Table                         BlogPostTags Table

ID  Name                          BlogID    TagID
----------------                  ----------------
1   Dogs                            1         1
2   Cats                            1         9
3   Birds                           1         11
4   Horses
5   Rabbits
6   Reptiles
7   Insects
8   Nature
9   Puppies
10  Kittens
11  Cute
12  Products
```

But what really happens is that it creates NEW tags with IDs into the Tags Table. Like so

```
Tag Table                         BlogPostTags Table

ID  Name                          BlogID    TagID
----------------                  ----------------
1   Dogs                            1         13
2   Cats                            1         14
3   Birds                           1         15
4   Horses
5   Rabbits
6   Reptiles
7   Insects
8   Nature
9   Puppies
10  Kittens
11  Cute
12  Products
13  Dogs
14  Puppies
15  Cute
```

Ovbviously duplicate Names are no good! how can I fix this so that I get the expected result? Heres my ActionResult Method

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Title,PublishDate,PublishTime,Body,AuthorID,Tags")] CreateBlogPostVM blogpost)
{
    List<Tag> tags = new List<Tag>();
    foreach (var tag in blogpost.Tags.Where(t => t.IsChecked == true))
    {
        tags.Add(new Tag { TagID = tag.TagID, Name = tag.Name });
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        BlogPost newPost = new BlogPost
        {
            Title = blogpost.Title,
            PublishDate = blogpost.PublishDate,
            PublishTime = blogpost.PublishTime,
            Body = blogpost.Body,
            Author = db.Authors.Where(bp => bp.AuthorID == blogpost.AuthorID).Single(),
            Tags = tags //Add list of tags 
        };
        db.BlogPosts.Add(newPost);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(blogpost);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the EXISTING tags that already exist in your db rather than adding new ones. Replace this:

```
        foreach (var tag in blogpost.Tags.Where(t => t.IsChecked == true))
        {
            tags.Add(new Tag { TagID = tag.TagID, Name = tag.Name });
        }
```

with:

```
        foreach (var tag in blogpost.Tags.Where(t => t.IsChecked == true))
        {
            tags.Add(db.Tags.Find(tag.TagID));
        }
```

(this assumes TagID is the primary key for your tag table, if not you can do something like `tags.Add(db.Tags.Where(t=>t.TagID == tag.TagID).First())`)

Comment: Works perfectly, I wasn't too sure of the right way to do it. Thanks